# JWT / RefreshToken in Flutter with ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy / Interceptor

Tags: flutter, interceptor, refresh-token

I'm trying to use an **InterceptorContract** to intercept my calls and check whether my refreshtoken has expired.

I would like to handle a 401 by requesting a new token and retrying the previous request, however I can't figure out how to implement this using the ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy/http_interceptor. Does anyone have a suggestion or an example on how to implement this?

I looked at the example in the [http_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/http_interceptor) package but that didn't really make it clear.

[ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA5hn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a few things, I found out that I could add the policy in the constructor of the http interceptor:
[add policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rExUH.png)

and then call the retry policy in my method after getting a 401
[call retry policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M71EG.png)

In my shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse I check if it's a 401, and then I call the
function to refresh my function.

Probably not the best way to do this, but it works :)